# UIPopoverPresentationController is not showing buttons and other UI elements

Tags: ios

I am trying to create a viewController to be presented as popOver. But all the elements in the view are not visible at all.

```
LoadValueViewController *destinationViewController = (LoadValueViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loadValue"];
destinationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sender;
destinationViewController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = ((UIView *)sender).bounds;
[self presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When I am adding components programatically in viewDidLoad of LoadValueViewController, it is then visible. But by adding the component in IB, it doesn't appear.

[image]

Comment: please provide screenshot or code snippet

Comment: add your code and we can see whats the problem

Comment: it seems when i set auto layout the element get disappeard